# Little languages similar to the "picture language" in SICP

Tags: scheme, sicp

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) section 2.2.4 describes a little "picture language" to build complicated image patters. The language defines a single primitive `painter` to draw an image within a given frame and functions to transform and combine `painters` to create a new `painter`.

I like this example and want to see more examples of such languages (preferably in `Scheme`). I would perfer languages for system/business domain. Are you aware of any of such little languages ?

Comment: Have you heard of [Logo](http://www.calormen.com/jslogo/)?

Comment: Logo is a programming language which is used to teach 6 year old kids how to program. It does so using turtle graphics. For example to draw a square you would move forward `x` units, turn right 90 degrees, and so on 4 times. It also teaches children abstraction by teaching them how to teach the turtle new commands (i.e. defining functions). For example you could define a function to make the turtle draw a square and a triangle and then use those functions to make the turtle draw a house. In addition Logo is very similar to Lisp. It was created by Seymour Papert while he was in MIT. That helps?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it helps. However I would prefer a little language for everyday tasks in system/business domain. (I will update the question)

Comment: Abelson says Lisp* is the tool to make the tool to solve your problems. That means you solve every problem you have by doing this. (* They called Scheme Lisp in the video lectures)

Answer (score 2):

These "little" languages also known as [Domain-specific languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) or DSL. It is widely used programming paradigm, but it has its advantages and disadvantages.

For example there is a commercial general game playing system, called [Zillions of Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zillions_of_Games). It uses [S-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression), so its syntax looks very familiar if you know Lisp. In fact any game scripting language is a DSL.

If you are web developer, you often deal with template languages. And you can think about template language as a domain specific language too. Some of them could be extended, like [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/), via custom template tags.

Some of current general programming languages was initially developed as domain specific languages. For example, [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) was initially designed by Ericsson for telephony applications.

Answer (score 1):

Every well designed program of any size will have one or more 'picture languages' in it.  To find examples try [MIT Scheme](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/projects/scheme/) or [Schemers.org](http://www.schemers.org)